# Why does the remainder operator fail with different data types?

Tags: c, gcc

I encountered an annoying bug in my code:

```
length = 60;
index = -1;
rem = index % length;
```

In the debugger, I saw that `rem` had value 15, instead of -1, which didn't make any sense to me. It turned out that `length` was of type **unsigned int** and `index` was of type **int**. Changing the type of `length` to *int* resolved the issue.

However, I don't understand what went wrong. Given the definition of the remainder operation (`(a/b)*b + a%b == a`), I had maybe expected a sign error due to the different types, but I had not expected the random value of 15. (Although 60/4 = 15, so maybe some bits got shifted?)

My question is: why did the remainder operation fail when presented with a signed and an unsigned integer as operands? Which implementation details can cause this?

(Using gcc 4.8.2)

Comment: @nos: Reopened. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 1 unsigned and 1 signed variable as operands to the binary operator `%`, in this casethe signed variable is converted to an unsigned type. (You can read a summary of these conversion rules [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules))

So your -1 is converted to an unsigned value, which will be (assuming int is 32 bit) `0xffffffff`
`0xffffffff % 60` is `15`

Comment: That answers the question. I had expected that the unsigned integer would be converted to signed integer, because you don't loose information. BUT, I realize now that you can't do that since the range of the unsigned integer wouldn't fit into the signed integer.